# Как правильно изменять state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть элемент инпута

```
<Input type='text' onChange={this.onEmailChanged} value={this.state.email} placeholder="Email"/>
```

Функция обработки:

```
onEmailChanged = (e) => {
this.setState({
    email: e.target.value
})
console.log(this.state.email);
}
```

Но когда я изменяю стейт вводя данные он изменяется с задержкой, вот так:

ввел 't' => консоль : (пусто)

ввел 'test@mail.ru' => консоль : 'test@mail.r'

подскажите, как избавиться от такого эффекта?

Answer (score 0):

Ты правильно изменяешь state. Но дело в том, что это асинхронная операция, и что бы выполнить некий код(в твоем случае вывод в консоль) **только после того** как произошла мутация состояния, можно, например, использовать callback функцию:

```
this.setState(
  {
    email: e.target.value
  },
  () => {
    console.log(this.state.email);
  }
);
```